# Почему не работает $router.addRoutes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Ситуация такая, при инициализации в объекте route три объекта маршрутов:

```
var routes = [
{ name: 'a', path: '/', component: Start },
{ name: 'b', path: '/signup', component: SignUp, alias: '/sign' }
{ name: 'd', path: '*', component: NotFound }]
```

При успешной авторизации пользователя в приложении ему должен быть доступен его личный кабинет по адресу: '/user'. Реализуется это путем добавления к объекту router нового объекта маршрута:

```
this.$router.addRoutes([{ name: 'c', path: '/user', component: User }]);
```

Но при попытке перехода по данному маршруту меня терпит неудача(( а именно редирект на маршрут 'd':
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть собстна, Господа?)

```js
Vue.use(Router)
var routes = [
    { name: 'a', path: '/', component: Start },
    { name: 'b', path: '/signup', component: SignUp, alias: '/sign' },
    { name: 'd', path: '*', component: NotFound }
]

var router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
})

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    router: router,
    data: function() { 
      return {
        message: 'Hello'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addNewUrl: function(mes) {
        this.$router.addRoutes([{ name: 'c', path: '/user', component: User }]);
        console.log(this.$router);  // получаю все те же самые три маршрута 'a', 'b', 'd'
    },
    }
```

P.S. при вызове метода push "не отходя от кассы" переход успешен, но увы, при возврате к стартовой странице '/' или регистрации '/signup' повторный переход к '/user' невозможен(((

```
this.$router.addRoutes([{ name: 'c', path: '/user', component: User }]);
this.$router.push('/user');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> При успешной авторизации пользователя в приложении ему должен быть
>   доступен его личный кабинет по адресу: '/user'. Реализуется это путем
>   добавления к объекту router нового объекта маршрута

Не надо так делать. Надо объявить СРАЗУ все маршруты, но проверять статус пользователя, что он вошёл в систему.

Файл router.js

```
import store from '../store';

Vue.use(Router);

const ifNotAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next();
    return;
  }
  next('/');
};

const ifAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next();
    return;
  }
  next('/login');
};

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'DashboardMain',
      component: DashboardMain,
      beforeEnter: ifNotAuthenticated,
    },
    {
      path: '/Login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login,
      beforeEnter: ifNotAuthenticated,
    },
    {
      path: '/Accounts/All',
      name: 'AccountsAll',
      component: AccountsAll,
      beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: Оу, спасибо большое за такой подробный ответ, но если Вас не заруднит, не могли бы пояснить, что такое store, почему не надо так делать (в связи с безопасностью?) и что нужно почитать, чтобы понять, что такое ifAuthenticated/ifNotAuthenticated = (to, from, next) ??

Comment: Как я уже догадываюсь, store - это объект класса Vuex, верно?)

Comment: @ivankalita_ Верно, это [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/), но вы можете использовать и свой какой-то механизм. Второй вопрос: читайте про [навигационные хуки](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) Почему не нужно делать: потому что у вас в приложении появляется состояние. Всё что объявлено/создано статически гораздо проще в программировании/отладке/сопровождении, чем динамическое подключение/удаление плагинов/модулей/функциональности.

Comment: Чертовски благодарен Вам, @A K, ответ засчитал за правильный, не знаю чем еще могу отблагодарить)). Спасибо за содействие!!!

Comment: @ivankalita_ Спасибо, этого вполне достаточно.